# id to int conversion from NSMutableDictionary to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm loading numbers from a `.plist` file, with values of either 0 or 1.

I then load these values into an `NSArray`.

Then I want to be able to do

```
if([levelOkays[1] == 1){
    [play1 setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [play1 setEnabled:true]; // To toggle enabled / disabled
}else{
    [play1 setTitle:@"Locked" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [play1 setEnabled:false]; // To toggle enabled / disabled
}
```

Where `levelOkay` is an `NSArray`. The problem is, I can't do the `== 1` because the values in the array are id's and 1 is an integer. How do I convert from one to the other.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this, looks more elegant if your values are truly either `0` and `1` in the array.

```
BOOL _isOkay = [levelOkays[1] boolValue];
[play1 setTitle:(_isOkay ? @"Play" : @"Locked") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[play1 setEnabled:_isOkay];
```

## or

if you don't need the boolean at all:

```
[play1 setEnabled:[levelOkays[1] boolValue]];
[play1 setTitle:(play1.isEnabled ? @"Play" : @"Locked") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Clean, I like this approach

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `intValue` method:

```
if (levelOkays[1].intValue == 1)
```

or if they're really only booleans, then use `boolValue`.

Answer (score 1):

When you load a `NSArray` from a plist, the numbers from the plist will be loaded as `NSNumber`s. (Assuming the plist encodes the type correctly, `<integer>`)

You can compare the number to the int as follows:

```
if ([levelOkays[1] integerValue] == 1)
```